# Drag and Drop feature is not working in Android Studio. Can't even click to show attributes

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.2

I want to drag and drop elements into the Design View but I just can't. I can't even see the attributes aside when click into the screen or the default TextView that says 'Hello World!'. I tried restarting Android Studio, rebuild the project, and I still have the problem.

The code below is from my file 'activity_main.xml'.

How did happened?
I just tried to add a 'GridLayout' into the screen design, but to use it I had to install a library to use that grid layout and since I did that, I can't use the design view anymore.

Even I get an 'IDE Fatal Error' (screenshot below).

error ide image:
[image: error ide image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
from your build.gradle (app) 
Hopefully Solve this problem

Comment: Please add more explaination and detail that other users could understand it well.